# Page Content not displaying in Wordpress Klean Theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a new splash page going up and everything works well except, none of the page content displays. Pages come up in menu but no content anywhere.

I've looked over all the other answers but they have to do with mistakes in editing php code. I have a brand new website on the WP Klean theme, I've done a bit of custom CSS but nothing too weird and no PHP editing. No one on the Klean theme support has had issues that I can see.

I've tried:
-Editing the CSS to make sure it isn't a display issue (can't find the content on inspector either so assuming it's not there)
- deleting and republishing pages
- changes font styles on visual editor for pages
- disabling pluggins

I'm also a complete newbie to web dev so I hope this is not an incredibly stupid question, usually I fix any problems through Google but I'm completely stuck.

The site is at www.abocare.com

Thanks a mil!

Comment: The content is all there, it is just hidden.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, this line is getting added to the page:


#page {
display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a plugin installed that is doing this.  It is probably called something like wp-custom-css.  There is a line in the css it is adding to the code that is hiding all of your page content:

```
#page {
display: none !important;
}
```

If you don't have a plugin, it may be part of your theme that allows you to easily add css.